# Looping tricky data set names

Tags: r

The data set is titled according to the months (19 months in total). The title looks like, for instance: `sub_1410_file`. The middle part is 1701, 1702, ... for 19 months. I'm a total newbie in R and have trouble understanding how to bring in these data sets.

I have tried the following but the "file names" are created as dummy characters, not as themselves.

```
times<- c(1410, 1411, 1412, ..., 1604)
names <- rep("", length(times))

for(i in 1: length(times)){
  names[i] <- paste("sub", as.character(times[i]), 
                    "file", sep="")
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to import files from your files system or do operations on objects that are already within your R session?

Comment: to create the names use `paste("sub",times,"file",sep="_")` but this wont be necessary. If all the files are in one folder, use the `list.files` which will list all the files you want. if the files are in an R session already, use the `ls` function.

Comment: @Onyambu I believe the OP wants `sep = ""`. Or `paste0`. Anyway, no need for a loop.

Comment: Just to complete @Onyambu comment, `list.files` can be used like this: `list.files(pattern="sub_\\d+_file")` as long as you set your working directory where your files are.